# Drupal - Backup and Migrate Module MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I recently tried backing up my production site and uploading the content to a barbones drupal installation running locally. When I do the restore I get the following error about 15 seconds into the update:

```
    PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or

 update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails in 

backup_migrate_destination_db_mysql->_restore_db_from_file() (line 201 of /Applications

/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/devProject/sites/all/modules/backup_migrate/includes

/destinations.db.mysql.inc).
```

I checked line 201 and it is where the module process the mysql from the backup one line at a time: `$stmt->execute();`

The module version I am running is:  `Backup and Migrate 2 for Drupal 7.x`

After my the import fails I get PHP errors that kill my local site.

Comment: That error kind of feels like you didn't have enough memory allocated and a backup failed part way through. Did you configure your local php.ini to increase php memory? You'll likely want to start from a fresh install and try again. Can you share the memory bits of your php configuration?

Comment: You might get better results at [SE's Drupal site](http://drupal.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to manually delete all the tables and do the import from phpmyadmin or something